# Is vocal resonance a characteristic of (some) Portuguese accents?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, fonologia

In the few times I have had the opportunity to listen to Portuguese people speak, I couldn't help but notice that they are much more likely to use vocal resonance than Brazilian speakers (see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xv8tMnWXdss), for example). Some Brazilian speakers use vocal resonance too (see [Magnoli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmrPs019Sc0), e.g.), but I feel it is a much rarer phenomenon. Can I think of this resonance as one defining characteristic of accents from Portugal, similar to them being stress-timed instead of syllable-timed, or is the difference I feel just a manifestation of the happenstance of whom I happened to listen to?

(By the way, I am Brazilian. I am only writing this question in English because my keyboard is not currently configured to type Portuguese accent marks, so please feel free to write answers in Portuguese.)